# Linux on Laptops

Tags: linux-kernel, laptop, hardware-compatibility

Good evening.
I have an acer notebook running in dualboot configuration with Fedora 25 and Windows 10. I would like to know if it is possible to irreversible damage the notebooks hardware by linux not having functional i2c drivers, like fan control or something else. How does the linux-kernel prevent unknown hardware from malfunctioning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Generally fans and similar are handled by the BIOS now, or on-board controllers. The OS can control these also via ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface). But the lack of control here would typically not be a threat. Also if your linux distro does not control "aperfmperf", this does not mean your cpu will not function, the mhz will simply be adjusted by the BIOS instead. However if your kernel has the modules for aperf/mperf it can adjust the cpu frequency.